# Cron job error outputting failed loading of ioncube loader

Tags: magento, pdo, cron

I recently moved from php 4 to 5. I had my server people look and ioncube loader is installed properly. I'm at a loss of what this is and what to actually do. I have magento 1.9 so I have the cron job set up every minute to output the sales emails (like I read in other places)

Thanks for your help.

```
Failed loading /usr/local/IonCube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so: /usr/local/IonCube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so: undefined symbol: execute
Zend Guard Loader requires Zend Engine API version 220100525.
The Zend Engine API version 220121212 which is installed, is newer.
Contact Zend Technologies at http://www.zend.com/ for a later version of Zend Guard Loader.

X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.21
Content-type: text/html


<b>Fatal error</b>: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception' with message 'The PDO extension is required for this adapter but the extension is not loaded' in /home/xxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:342
Stack trace:
#0 /home/xxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(248): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract-&gt;setFetchMode(2)
#1 /home/xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(175): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract-&gt;__construct(Array)
#2 /home/xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource-&gt;_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#3 /home/xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource-&gt;getConnection('core_write')
#4 /home/xxxy/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract-&gt;_getConnection('write')
#5 /home/xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/ in <b>/home/xxx/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php</b> on line <b>342</b><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

You installed the ionCube Loaders for PHP 5.4 (as indicated by the filename), yet you have PHP 5.5 installed (`X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.21`).

You can download the appropriate ionCube Loaders from [here](http://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php), or use the Loader Wizard available here ([zip](http://www.ioncube.com/loader-wizard/loader-wizard.zip), [tgz](http://www.ioncube.com/loader-wizard/loader-wizard.tgz)) to help with the installation; in any case you'll have to remove the `zend_extension = <path to the outdated loaders/>` line from your `php.ini` and restart your PHP/Apache process to remove the outdated Loader extension.